# how to use add and remove button in two select box and submit in database

Tags: javascript, php

**HTML** :

```
 <form method="post">
     <fieldset>

    <select name="selectfrom[]" id="select-from" multiple size="5">
      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      <option value="4">Item 4</option>
    </select>

    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>

    <select name="selectto[]" id="select-to[]" multiple size="5">

    </select>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**javascript** :

```
<script>       
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        $('#select-from[] option:selected').each( function() {
                $('#select-to[]').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
        $('#select-to[] option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#select-from[]').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: in first select javascript code correct the 'id'

Comment: Can u able to add the function / server side code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with id selector, change `select-to` instead of `select-to[]` in HTML and jQuery.

To get options value on submit, use `map()`

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
       var toSelected = $('#select-to option').map(function(){
          return $(this).val();
       }).get().join(',');
       console.log("TO SELECTED: "+ toSelected);

       var fromSelected = $('#select-from option').map(function(){
          return $(this).val();
       }).get().join(',');
       console.log("FROM SELECTED: "+ fromSelected);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
                $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
        $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
    $('#submitButton').click(function(){
      
       var toSelected = $('#select-to option').map(function(){
          return $(this).val();
       }).get().join(',');
      
       console.log("TO SELECTED: "+ toSelected);
      
       var fromSelected = $('#select-from option').map(function(){
          return $(this).val();
       }).get().join(',');
      
       console.log("FROM SELECTED: "+ fromSelected);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
     <fieldset>

    <select name="selectfrom[]" id="select-from" multiple size="5">
      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      <option value="4">Item 4</option>
    </select>

    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>

    <select name="selectto[]" id="select-to" multiple size="5">

    </select>
    <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: i am not able to submit ' selectto[ ] ' value in database

Answer (score 0):

Since `[` and `]` is a meta characters, use `\\` to escape it.

```
$('#select-to\\[\\]')
```

instead of

```
$('#select-to[]')
```

[**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#btn-add').click(function() {
    $('#select-from\\[\\] option:selected').each(function() {
      $('#select-to\\[\\]').append("<option value='" + $(this).val() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
  $('#btn-remove').click(function() {
    $('#select-to\\[\\] option:selected').each(function() {
      $('#select-from\\[\\]').append("<option value='" + $(this).val() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <fieldset>

    <select name="selectfrom[]" id="select-from[]" multiple size="5">
      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      <option value="4">Item 4</option>
    </select>

    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>

    <select name="selectto[]" id="select-to[]" multiple size="5">
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: can i pass id instead of name in add or remove

Comment: @nik, yes you can. You need to elaborate. Learn how to use apis  https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: how to pass id instead of name in add and remove button